# Android App Updated Version

Tags: android

How can I preserve my android app's code then edit (add features or fix some bugs) to obtain an updated version of the app (ex: v:1.1), so that I can return to my (v1) version of the app if I want so. 
I'm using Android Studio. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what've you tried, googled yet?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have `version code` which must be update to upload a new version to the market. You have `version name` as well which can be anything you want — this is human-readable field.

[Versioning docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)